# Am I able to redeem a Borderlands 2 shift key without launching the game?

Tags: borderlands-2

Gearbox released a shift code, but unfortunately I am not in a position to redeem it in the normal way, i.e. launch BL2 and enter the code.  Is there a way to redeem this code if I have access to the Internet, but not to my installation of the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this point in time there is no way to redeem your [SHiFT](https://shift.gearboxsoftware.com/) key without launching the game. However, you are able to link your Steam, Xbox Live and/or Sony Entertainment Network as a gaming platform in preparation to launching the game. Source: Myself & [Gearbox Forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=179095)